# Using a RESTful Web Service for retrieving data from a MySql database

Tags: c#, php, mysql, xamarin.forms

I'm doing a cross-platform app using Xamarin.forms and I need to retrieve data from a MySql Server. Through my research, i found that it wasn't secure to use the MySqlClient library so I searched for doing that using a Web Service layer between my database and the app.

This code make the query to the MySql database, output the results in an array and echo them in JSON encoding. Here is the PHP code :

```
<?php
$servername = "adress";
$username = "client";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dnName";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT text1, text2 FROM tblTable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $items = array();
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $item = array("Texte1" => $row['text1'],
                                         "Texte2" => $row['text2']);
        array_push($items, $item);
    }
    echo json_encode($items);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This code call a PHP file, get the response and convert them into a List of Items. Here is the C# code :

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
//....

    private Uri uri;
    private HttpClient client;
    private List<Items> item;

    public async Task<List<Items>> ReadData()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        uri = new Uri("http://adress/getdata.php");

        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Items>>(content);
        }
        return item;
    }

    public class Items
    {
        public string text1 { get; set;}
        public string text2 { get; set;}
    }
```

So now, the return type of the ReadData method is a `List<Items>` but how can I return them in a `List<string>` or a simply string ?

Comment: What would be the format of the expected string?

Comment: @MatiasCicero Maybe like the PHP code output when I run it without the C# code :

[{"Texte1":"sometext","Texte2":"anothertext"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some options with Linq (dont forget to include "using System.Linq;"). I prefer working with option 2

1. Returning an anonymous type:

   ```
   var mylist = item.Where(x => x != null)
                       .Select(x => new { x.text1, x.text2 }).ToList();
   ```
2. Returning a List of list of strings:

   ```
   List<List<string>> mylist = listItems.Where(x => x != null)
                             .Select(x => new List<string>{ x.text1, x.text2}).ToList();
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but where I have to put this code ?

Comment: before returning item in your ReadData() method.

Comment: However this will return an Anonymous type, which is more close to the type that you wanted.
I will edit my answer so that you could avoid working anonymous types. See if it suits your needs

Comment: I have an error because I can't return an Anonymous type because with my configuration, my return type should be a `List<Items>`. So in this case what type of List do I have to put where I have `public async Task<List<Items>> ReadData()`?

Comment: If I have understood correctly, you wanted to change the return type of your ReadData() method to a List of strings right? 
I gave you an option to return a List<List<string>> , then you should modify your method to public async Task<List<List<string>> ReadData()

Comment: Yeah it's the goal. Now, how can I display a List of List of string ?

Comment: display in the console?

Comment: So how ? I tried :

`for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count(); i++)
   {
    for (int j = 0; i < mylist.Count(); j++)
    {
     Debug.WriteLine(mylist[i][j]); 
    }
   }`

It doesn't work.

Comment: foreach (var item in mylist){ Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(",",item));}

Comment: Note that you can even convert it to a List<string> if you want or even a string: 

            List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in mylist) { stringList.Add((string.Join(",", item))); }

stringList in this example will be a List<string>

Comment: you are welcome, if this is the answer , please mark it as answer =)